Understanding matrix representation of tensor products
My course material for linear algebra has this question, and I'm not sure on how to do it:
For a linear operator $L$ on $V$, we can create a linear operator on $V\otimes V$ by $I\otimes L - L\otimes I$, where $I$ is the identity on $V$. If $L$ is given by the matrix
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
What is the matrix for $I\otimes L - L\otimes V$?
I don't understand how to start or how to finish. I know about the Kronecker product, but it does not give me any meaningful insight into what is really happening and how these tensor products work. Should i look at $(I\otimes L)(e_i\otimes e_j)$ where $\{ e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis for say $\mathbb{C}^2$, and then try to represent it in a basis for $V\otimes V$ like $\{e_i \otimes e_j\}_{i\in I,j\in J}$? My problem is that I don't really understand how to represent tensor products in a basis or how to "work" with them.

Do you mean $I\otimes L - L\otimes I$? I'm only learning multilinear algebra now myself so am no expert, just wondering since I haven't seen $I\otimes L - L\otimes V$ before. If not, then can I ask what textbook you're following if there is one?

Yes, i fixed it now @Tom

Yes you should look at the action on the elements of the basis at first

This is something you should be able to find on the net. For example, https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/nedlagte-emner/MAT-INF2360/v12/tensortheory.pdf

This question is a duplicate of: Matrix Representation of the Tensor Product of Linear Maps.

$\def\kp{\color{red}{\otimes}}  \def\cM{\cal M}$
$L \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ e_2 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\ e_2 \end{bmatrix} $. The basis of $V \otimes V$ is $\{e_i \otimes e_j\}_{i,j=1,2}$. $(I \otimes L)( v_1 \otimes v_2) := Iv_1 \otimes L v_2$.
$$  (I \otimes L - L \otimes I)  \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \otimes e_1 \\ e_1 \otimes e_2 \\ e_2 \otimes e_1 \\ e_2 \otimes e_2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} Ie_1 \otimes Le_1-Le_1 \otimes I e_1 \\ Ie_1 \otimes Le_2 - Le_1 \otimes Ie_2 \\ Ie_2 \otimes Le_1 - Le_2 \otimes Ie_1 \\ Ie_2 \otimes Le_2 - Le_2 \otimes I e_2  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} e_1 \otimes (e_1+2e_2)-(e_1+2e_2) \otimes e_1 \\ e_1 \otimes (4e_1 + 3e_2) - (e_1+2e_2) \otimes e_2 \\ e_2 \otimes (e_1+2e_2) - (4e_1+3e_2) \otimes e_1 \\ e_2 \otimes (4e_1+3e_2) - (4e_1+3e_2) \otimes  e_2  \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 2e_1 \otimes e_2 -2e_2 \otimes e_1 \\ 4e_1 \otimes e_1 + 2 e_1 \otimes e_2- 2 e_2 \otimes e_2 \\ - 4 e_1 \otimes e_1-2e_2 \otimes e_1+ 2 e_2 \otimes e_2  \\   - 4 e_1 \otimes e_2 + 4e_2\otimes  e_1  \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & -2 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & 0 & -2 \\
-4 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & -4 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} e_1 \otimes e_1 \\ e_1 \otimes e_2 \\ e_2 \otimes e_1 \\ e_2 \otimes e_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
We could have saved a lot of work by noting that the Kronecker product $\kp$ (which generates a matrix and not a tensor) of the matrix representations $[I],[L]$ of respectively $I,L$
$$
[I] \kp [L] - [L] \kp [I]
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\kp 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
4 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
4 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\kp
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\4 & 3 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 2\\0 & 0 & 4 & 3\end{matrix}\right]
-\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 2\\4 & 0 & 3 & 0\\0 & 4 & 0 & 3\end{matrix}\right]
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & -2 & 0 \\
4 & 2 & 0 & -2 \\
-4 & 0 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & -4 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What do you mean when you write
$$
(I \otimes L - L \otimes I) e_i \otimes e_j =  (I \otimes L - L \otimes I)  \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \otimes e_1 \ e_1 \otimes e_2 \ e_2 \otimes e_1 \ e_2 \otimes e_2 \end{bmatrix}?
$$
Is this some standard abuse of notation?

@BenGrossmann you are right, it is confusing. I have deleted the $(I \otimes L - L \otimes I) e_i \otimes e_j$ part.
